# How to rewrite part of url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have

```
www.site.com/m/pages/view/mydog
```

and want to rewrite to

```
www.site.com/page/mydog
```

I have rule

```
RewriteRule ^m/pages/view/(.*)$  $page/  [NC]
```

but it doesn't do the job.

How can I do this?

### UPDATE

Basically the script add to the url a "m" which stands for "module" and then the type of module, and then "view" when we access the page of each module type.
Solution here is to remove every /m/ and every /view/ from every url

site.com/m/pages/view/mydog

Comment: I'm using boonex script, and the only rule related to pages I commented it:
# RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$  viewPage.php?ID=$1 [QSA,L

Comment: structure is public_html/test/1/2/sitehere (is this also relevant?)

Comment: full .htaccess here http://snipt.org/Agfjb3

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to insert the text after `view/`

```
RewriteRule ^m/pages/view/(.*)$  page/$1  [NC]
```

Comment: it does nothing with it

Comment: In which directory did you place the .htaccess file? Did you define the RewriteBase directive? Could it be something external to the rewrite engine?

Comment: I'm working on test site located in public_html/test/1/2/sitehere, and removed the .htaccess from the  public_html/ , also deactivated the url friendly option of the boonex script, still it does nothing

Comment: Do you want this rule to be passed through the next lines in the .htaccess? You might want to add the flag L: [NC,L]